# MousEvent isn't working because the MouseListener implement is acting weirdly

Tags: java, mouseevent, mouselistener, mousemotionlistener

I've been busy with this for the last half hour but I can't figure out why my Handlerclass keeps giving an error about a method not being abstract while I implement every single method MouseListener and MouseMotionListener need. Please help. Here's the code:

```
public class PanelClass extends JFrame {
private JPanel m;
private JLabel s;

public PanelClass() {
    super("Testing");

    m = new JPanel();
    m.setBackground(Color.RED);
    add(m, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    s = new JLabel("Hello and welcome. We're showing you what your mouse does in this bar. Let's get started!");
    add(s, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    Handlerclass handler = new Handlerclass();
    m.addMouseListener(handler);
    m.addMouseMotionListener(handler);

}

private class Handlerclass implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {


    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
        s.setText("You cliced the mouse.");
    }


    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
        s.setText(String.format ("You pressed the mouse"));
    }


    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
        s.setText("You ain't clickin' shit boi..");
    }


    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {
        s.setText("The mouse has entered the panel..");
        m.setBackground(Color.PINK);
    }


    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {
        s.setText("The mouse has left the panel..");
        m.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
       s.setText("You been dragging. ");
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event) {
        s.setText("Moving around.");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: can you copy the message?

Comment: What does you `import`s look like?  Are you importing `java.awt.event.MouseEvent` or `javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent` or `org.wc.dom.events.MouseEvent` or some other `MosueEvent`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer 
    import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

Comment: I've thrown your code into an IDE (fixed the imports) and it compiles fine for me. Maybe try doing a clean and build and even rebooting if that fails to fix the issue